# Appending json response to a list

Tags: python, json, list, append, jupyter-notebook

I'm having trouble appending a json response into a list. I'm sure it's a simple error but have spent hours trying to figure this out . . . any suggestion(s) would be greatly appreciated.

```
edd_areas = ["San Francisco-Redwood City-South San Francisco MD", 
             "Los Angeles-Long Beach-Glendale MD", 
             "Oakland-Hayward-Berkeley MD",
             "California"]

edd_year = []

edd_url = "https://data.edd.ca.gov/resource/4ezp-3bs3.json?"

for area in edd_areas:
    edd_query_url = edd_url + "area_name=" + area + "&seasonally_adjusted_y_n=N"
    edd_qresponse = requests.get(edd_query_url).json

    edd_year.append(edd_qresponse["year"])

Error: 
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-f3a906010984> in <module>()
     17 
     18 
---> 19     edd_year.append(edd_qresponse["year"])

TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: try `edd_year.append(edd_qresponse[0]["year"])`

Comment: Thanks. Still get same error. Here's a sample of the json data:

Comment: [
{
"area_name": "Oakland-Hayward-Berkeley MD",
"area_type": "Metropolitan Area",
"date": "1990-01-01T00:00:00.000",
"employment": "1068800",
"labor_force": "1111400",
"month": "January",
"seasonally_adjusted_y_n": "N",
"status_preliminary_final": "Final",
"unemployment": "42600",
"unemployment_rate": "3.8",
"year": "1990"

Comment: Are you sure your output variable `edd_qresponse` has json format data?  check this https://repl.it/@MahmutKilic/OfficialBelatedStack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

The first issue is in `requests.get(edd_query_url).json`. `.json` is a method and doesn't return json data, you were probably trying to do `.json()` instead and actually get the data.

The second issue is that the actual json data is a list so you can't index it by strings like "year".

Putting everything together:

```
edd_areas = ["San Francisco-Redwood City-South San Francisco MD", 
         "Los Angeles-Long Beach-Glendale MD", 
         "Oakland-Hayward-Berkeley MD",
         "California"]

edd_year = []

edd_url = "https://data.edd.ca.gov/resource/4ezp-3bs3.json?"

for area in edd_areas:
    edd_query_url = edd_url + "area_name=" + area + "&seasonally_adjusted_y_n=N"
    edd_qresponse = requests.get(edd_query_url).json() # call the function!

    edd_year.append(edd_qresponse) # just append the list since you can't index by "year"
```

And you get something that looks like this:

```
[[{'area_name': 'San Francisco-Redwood City-South San Francisco MD', 'area_type': 'Metropolitan Area', 'date': '1990-01-01T00:00:00.000' ...
```

Comment: Thanks! Calling the json function worked. However, I do want to pull in the year, month, area, and unemployment rate into a list so I can convert to a dataframe. These are the other variables I'm trying to add: edd_year = []
edd_month = []
edd_date = []
edd_city = []
edd_rate = []

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-82cb8a4474d1> in <module>()
     16     edd_qresponse = requests.get(edd_query_url).json()
     17 
---> 18     edd_year.append(edd_qresponse["year"])
     19     edd_month.append(edd_qresponse["month"])
     20     edd_date.append(edd_qresponse["date"])

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: @ChrisB. as I mention above comment, since your json format is inside list, you need to call index first. try `edd_year.append(edd_qresponse[0]["year"])`